# access standard css files of old versions

Tags: visualforce, css

I'm working in the org that has a lot of legacy code. A previous developer has used standard styles to style the page in a way:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sCSS/29.0/sprites/123/Theme3/default/gc/extended.css"/>
```

But the version of salesforce styles have changed, and now on page loading I see the error: [image: error in chrome console]
And the page looks not as the customer expects it to see.
I've tried to apply version 40.0 of styles, the page has changed the appearance, but still doesn't look like it used to. I've tried to find styles of version 29, but was not able to. The only ways to fix the issue are either find styles of version 29 or style the page manually.

Does anybody know a way to find the sCss styles of version 29.0?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to style this manually as [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_using_salesforce_stylesheets.htm) says

> Salesforce stylesheets aren’t versioned, and the appearance and class
>   names of components change without notice. Salesforce strongly
>   recommends that you use Visualforce components that mimic the
>   look-and-feel of Salesforce styles instead of directly referencing—and
>   depending upon—Salesforce stylesheets.